# Why isn't execute permission needed to source a file?

Tags: bash, permissions, security

Someone asked [a question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999446/etc-profile-returns-error-permission-denied) about why they got `permission denied` when they entered in a Bash shell

```
/etc/profile
```

I know this is because the file has no execute permission. Even root cannot execute it (`sudo /path/to/file/with/no/execute/bits` fails with the uninformative error `sudo /path/to...: command not found`). I also know that root *can* enter a directory with no execute bits, so the absolute prohibition on executing non-executable files seems special. In chat, [Eliah Kagan opined that the reason root would not be able to execute non-executable files was to protect root](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/66387?m=41656876#41656876) (presumably, from accidentally executing dangerous code).

I briefly wondered why anyone would want to execute `/etc/profile` and thought that if anyone did want to execute it, they would probably actually want to `source` it (because it is a configuration file that sets environment and shell variables). I then realised that execute permission is not needed to `source` any regular file. But `source` executes the file in the current shell! The file can contain any command, and `. file` will go right ahead and execute it.

If execute permission is restricted to prevent accidental execution of potentially dangerous code, why is it possible to execute non-excutable files using the `source` command?

Comment: It's difficult to interpret a deliberate action like typing `. /etc/profile` as "accidental".    it's your responsibility to not burn out your remaining eye with the laser pointer.

Comment: [Because POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) "Unlike normal command search, however, the file searched for by the dot utility need not be executable." A proper answer should probably discuss this and compare POSIX `.` with `source` in `bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think executing a non-executable file fails *on purpose* to prevent accidental execution of potentially dangerous code. It’s just part of the semantics of `execve`: it fails with `EACCES` if “Execute permission is denied for the file or a script or ELF interpreter.” (I’m quoting from [the Linux `execve` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#ERRORS). [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) says something similar: “Search permission is denied for a directory listed in the new process image file’s path prefix, or the new process image file denies execution permission.”) Unix/Linux has never been particularly concerned with preventing users from blowing their own feet off.

I think the explanation is rather more prosaic: the specifications for execution and sourcing are different. Direct execution asks the kernel to execute a given command, and that enforces execution privileges. Sourcing a file is just specified as reading it and executing it; in fact [the `bash` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS) explicitly states that “The  file
              searched  for  in `PATH` need not be executable.” [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) “Unlike normal command search, however, the file searched for by the *dot* utility need not be executable.” (`.` is equivalent to `source`.)

Note that you can execute binaries even when they’re not executable, using a technique similar to sourcing them:

```
$ cp /bin/ls .
$ chmod 644 ls
$ /lib64/ld-2.26.so ./ls
```

[Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda)’s [point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419599/why-isnt-execute-permission-needed-to-source-a-file#comment754057_419599) about comparing `bash`’s `source` and POSIX `.` is interesting. In non-POSIX mode, if `source` is given an argument without a path, it tries to find it in the `PATH`, and if it doesn’t find it, looks in the current directory; in POSIX mode it doesn’t, because POSIX forbids this:

> Some older implementations searched the current directory for the *file*, even if the value of *PATH* disallowed it. This behavior was omitted from this volume of POSIX.1-2008 due to concerns about introducing the susceptibility to trojan horses that the user might be trying to avoid by leaving **dot** out of *PATH*.

That doesn’t really change much in the discussion at hand though since an argument with a path will be processed by `source` or `.` in any case. (And really you should always use a path, even if only relative, for `source` arguments, to avoid surprises when you try to `source` something which is *also* on your `PATH`. Try creating a file named `test` and sourcing that with `source test` in `bash` to see what I mean.)

Comment: That one about loading an executable with ld.so is well thought.